# How to Add bulk delete by ids in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add Bulk delete by ids in my Django rest framework project but stucked in views .py anyone knows how to implement this feature in my project?

here is my class in views.py :

```
class AssignmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """View for manage assignment APIs."""
    serializer_class = serializers.AssignmentSerializer
    queryset = Assgnment.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Retrieve recipes for authenticated user."""
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-id')
    

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """Return the serializer class for request."""
        if self.action == 'list':
            return serializers.AssignmentSerializer

        return self.serializer_class
    


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Create a Assignment."""
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

here is my URLs :

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from assignment import views


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('assignment', views.AssignmentViewSet)
router.register('tags', views.TagViewSet)


app_name = 'assignment'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

please let me know if you need more details about my project

Update***

I tried this method but not working:

```
class AssignmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ... existing code ...

    @action(detail=False, methods=['delete'])
    def delete_bulk(self, request):
        """Delete multiple assignments by ids."""
        assignment_ids = request.data.get('ids', [])
        self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user, id__in=assignment_ids).delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

my API payload:

```
curl -X 'DELETE' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/assignment/assignment/delete_bulk?ids=8,9' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Token 1376bfc2439f1347ab16b28fb9e83b83a4336984' \
  -H 'X-CSRFTOKEN: x5CfIVresmUTbpG5GlPKAthmZ26WrWv3R5W0etOuhMm5Tbs0skwJMhxDFsT1KxKB'
```

Comment: request.data would be the request body, not query params.

Comment: @coderanger can you please make changes i didn't understand

Comment: I think you are well in over your head and should ask for mentorship from someone else on your team.

Comment: @coderanger I'm in college doesn't know anyone who expert or learning Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get data from **query_params**:

```
data = request.query_params.get("id")
```

But a better approach in your case is to handle in body and serializer.
In your **serializers.py**:

```
class DeleteAssignmentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ids = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField())
```

And in Your **views.py** do something like this:

```
class AssignmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ... existing code ...

    @action(detail=False, methods=['delete'])
    def delete_bulk(self, request):
        """Delete multiple assignments by ids."""
        serializer = DeleteAssignmentSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ids = serializer.data
        self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user, id__in=ids).delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```